# Code like Bookworm Adventures in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do you animate if the button is correct and the other buttons are not correct

```
if(btnA.isCorrect){
            //btnA Animation
         } else if(btnB.isCorrect){
             //btnB Animation
         } else if (btnC.isCorrect){
             //btnC Animation
         } else {
             //btnD Animation
         }
```

I have that code inside the method  **UserSelect(int n)** wherein **n** determines the btnNumber in my buttons,
and I do think that this is the logic of what I wanted to do if the user selected the buttons

PS: if the user selected a button and it is correct, the player will attack an enemy, otherwise, the enemy will attack the player

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @EJoshuaS i have tried testing this code from brackeys tutorial on true or false buttons, but it won't work (i saw a comment on how to create a multiple choice from brackeys true or false tutorial series)

i was thinking of doing the tutorial given by unity for this, but it seems that they made things hard to code, using multiple scenes for a single multiple choice

I was wondering what's the best thing to do this, using the brackeys tutorial or unity's tutorial?

Comment: What do you mean by "Animate"? Do you have an Animator set on your Button with animations, or do you want to change the sprite directly or anything?

Comment: @Isuka I do have an animator trigger that should be triggered when the user selected the right answer (button). the Animator with animations it is.

Comment: So you have the int `n` that is determined by the player's input. Is that all? Are there any checks? You should have an `if` before this one to determine whether the player was successful or not. If they are, set btnA.isCorrect to true, etc.

Comment: @Shadowtail I have it inside the button